# Cannot cast string to int (php)

Tags: php, casting

I am trying to finish my question of the day script.  I have a random number generator (external) which is inserted into a table daily.  I take that number and pull the corresponding question from another table.

```
// Query 1
$query1 = "SELECT $field1 FROM $table1 WHERE id=1";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con1, $query1);

// Query 2
$query2 = "SELECT $field2 FROM $table2 WHERE QNum = $result1";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con2, $query2);

// Display question
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
    echo $row['question'];
}
```

`$result1` is pulling a random number, lets say its 9.  When `$result1` is used to pull the question, it doesn't work but when I replace `$result1` with number 9, it works.  I experimented with syntax and eventually figured it could be a problem with a string vice an integer.

I tried to cast it as an integer but it keeps assigning the value of `$result1` to 1.  I am at a loss.  I don't understand if the string is a 9, how converting it to an integer would change its value.

I feel like I've tried everything after days of experimenting out there but I am sure it is something very simple.  Please help.

Comment: Why not do it in a single query with a join?

Comment: You forgot to call `mysqli_fetch_array` on `$result`. It doesn't contain the value of the field, it contains a `mysqli_result` object.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, it's something very simple. You need to fetch the row to get the value:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
$qnum = $row[$field1];

$query2 = "SELECT $field2 FROM $table2 WHERE QNum = $qnum";
```

You seem to understand this in general, since you call `mysql_fetch_array` to get the results of the second query. Why should the first query be any different?

However, you can do all this in one query:

```
$query2 = "SELECT t2.$field2
           FROM $table1 t1
           JOIN $table2 t2 ON t1.$field1 = t2.QNum
           WHERE t1.id = 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whats returned in $result1 ??

it should be an object which cannot be used inside the second mysql query. First you have to get the value from that query by fetching the query.

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con1, $query1);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_NUM);
$random_number = $row[0];
```

this $random_number then can be used in the second query. hope this will fix your error.